# std string short-string optimization is there a way to find out max short size?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Stroustrup writes that

> string is usually implemented using the short-string optimization.
> That is, short string values are kept in the string object itself and
> only longer strings are placed on free store.
> How many characters can a ‘‘short’’ string have? That’s implementation
> defined, but ‘‘about 14 characters’’ isn’t a bad guess.

But is there a way to find out max "short" string size for my compiler?

Comment: You can look at the standard library code that shipped with your compiler.

Comment: *But is there a way to find out max "short" string size for my compiler?* -- The best bet is to look at the source code.  It is possible that the compiler may do different things based on optimization settings.

Comment: There might be a scheme with using a `std::basic_string` with a custom allocator, and adding characters to the string until the allocator is asked for storage.

Comment: You could keep adding characters to your string until the address returned by `std::string::data()` is no longer inside the string object itself.

Comment: just `std::string s("a"); std::cout << s.capacity()`